# Error : Insert After Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers, xampp, localhost

I am having some issues with this trigger in mysql. I am a beginner with triggers, procedures, events, etc... so Sry if my mistake is something easy to find. 
My Mysql Xampp version is: 4.5.1
And the mentioned trigger is:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER actualitzarStock
AFTER INSERT ON detallcompra
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE producte SET producte.stock = (producte.stock - 
detallcompra.quantitat) 
where producte.idProducte = detallcompra.idProducte
END
DELIMITER //
```

The error i'm recieving is just: "Error". So, thank you to everybody who is trying to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refer to the new row being added to `detallcompra`, you have to use `NEW`, not the table name.

```
CREATE TRIGGER actualitzarStock
AFTER INSERT ON detallcompra
FOR EACH ROW
    UPDATE producte 
    SET producte.stock = (producte.stock - NEW.quantitat) 
    where producte.idProducte = NEW.idProducte;
```

Comment: I saw the notice 30 seconds ago...thought it might have been a noob, so I finished my answer.

Comment: Hi! yes, i'm a noob xD. I've tried your solution, @Barmar, but it doesn't work, the message says: 
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER//
CREATE TRIGGER actualitzarStock
AFTER INSERT ON detallcompra
FOR ' at line 1"

Comment: How are you entering this? It sounds like you're using an interface that doesn't require you to change the delimiter, so get rid of the `DELIMTER` lines.

Comment: Yes, I did it now, and the mistake continues. I'm using phpMyadmin. Introducing this code: CREATE TRIGGER actualitzarStock
AFTER INSERT ON detallcompra
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE producte 
    SET producte.stock = (producte.stock - NEW.quantitat) 
    where producte.idProducte = NEW.idProducte
END;
And the mistake stills: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 8

Comment: You need a semicolon at the end of the `UPDATE` statement

Comment: You don't need `BEGIN` and `END` when there's just one statement. Try it now.

Comment: Finally, it works! But without the semicolon after the update. Thanks a lot man!